# Connect string of SQL Server for localhost in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, localhost, connection-string

I'm using SQL Server 2012 for my system, and using Entity Framework, Code first for access data base, my data base is local, but I can't connect using `SERVER=localhost;` in ConnectString

My `App.config` (Working)

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SystemContext" connectionString="Server=JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PizzariaDB;user=sa;password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

But, if I would install my system in an other computer, other data base, PC name is not JOHN-PC, so I need change it for a generic `ConnectString`
But when I change `JOHN-PC\SQLEXPRESS` for `localhost`, it is not work

What can I do for resolve this problem?

Comment: Does the other machine not have a sql instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you have `database` on other remote pc aswell you can use `dot` `.` instead of hardcoding machine name.

here `.` represents the `localmachine`.

Try This :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SystemContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PizzariaDB;user=sa;password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

but if you want to run your machine as database server and want to every other pc to communicate with your PC for Database activities you can use `IP address` of your machine in your `connection string`.

Comment: Okey, just wait more 3 minutes xD

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SystemContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PizzariaDB;user=sa;password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The dot points to the local machine.